# Unity однообразные уровни (и их вес)

Tags: unity3d

В моей игре есть много (штук 100) однообразных уровней, которые различаются только расстановкой всяких однообразных объектов. Каждый уровень у меня - это одна сцена. Но из-за этого у меня столько уровней увеличивают игру на 50 мб, что для простой игры не очень хорошо. все ли я правильно делаю? как это все подурезать?

Comment: Можно хранить позицию каждого изменяющегося объекта на каждом уровне в отдельном файле. XML или там JSON. И загружать нужные данные в зависимости от номера уровня и по данным расставлять объекту по уровню\

Comment: Сделать префабы уровней и загружать уже с позициями объектов(не знаю как у тебя все это выглядит)

Comment: попробую, спасибо.